# Displaying most recent comments in my def show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a bit of trouble displaying the most recent created comments based from the time/date that they were created in my `views/post/show.htmlerb` file. I just got my `posts_controller` to display the most recent created posts from the `def index action` but now in my `def show` action the following code doesn't work:

`@comment_date_order = Comment.find(params[:id]).comments.order('created_at DESC')`

this is my full posts_controller.rb file:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :vote]
  before_action :require_user, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :vote]
  before_action :require_creator, only:[:edit, :update]

  def index
    @posts = Post.page(params[:page]).order('created_at DESC').per_page(10)
  end

  def show
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment_date_order = Post.find(params[:id]).comments.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.creator = current_user

    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "You created a post!"
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update(post_params)
      flash[:notice] = "You updated the post!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def vote
    Vote.create(voteable: @post, creator: current_user, vote: params[:vote])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :vote } # Renders views/posts/vote.js.erb
    end
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:url, :title, :description)
  end

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def require_creator
    access_denied if @post.creator != current_user
  end
end
```

comments_controller.erb file:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(params.require(:comment).permit(:body))
    @comment.post = @post
    @comment.creator = current_user

    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your comment was created!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render 'posts/show'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end

  def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.update(comment_params)
      flash[:notice] = "You updated your comment!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end

  def set_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you would need a relation between Post and Comment if you dont already.

I would just create a def in the Post model.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  def newest_comments
    self.comments.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

That way you could also make a oldest_post method and uses it directly in the view

```
<%= @post.newest_post.each do |comment| %>
```

Also as best practice. Try and not to create too many instance vars in your controller. Remember fat models, skinny controllers.